# How to make a part follow a players x and z coordinates on roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

How to make a part follow a players x and z coordinates on roblox? I don't know a lot of luaR so I need some help. I'm making a plane and I want a part to follow your X and Z coordinates because max part size is 2048 so I don't want to keep copying that and a lot of terrain is laggy.

I tried to get a pet script from the toolbox and made the maxforce for Y 0 but it obviously didn't work because I don't know a lot of luaR.

Comment: I have difficulties seeing the connection between following something, the terrain and the max part size. So you want an object to stay relative to your plane? Would it make sense to just make that object relative to the plane?

Comment: I meant to say im making a plane game and i want to make infinite map using meshpart but then it wont have collisions so i want a 2048x2048 part to follow players x and z coordinates

Comment: But what stops you from doing that? Btw, did you consider making the airplane static and move the environment instead? Tends to be more stable.

Comment: A good place to start would be to include some of what you have tried! Share some code, or share as far as you've gotten to start and it will help people to give more specific tips or direction. 

If you have the time to read it, Stack overflow has a description of what makes a good question on this website: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.